# Error al validar usuario existente en la BD con PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Que tal buen día, al tratar de validar un usuario en PHP ejecuto la funcion var_dump() y esta me devuelve bool(false) lo cual es incorrecto ya que estoy ingresando un usuario que si existe en la base de datos por lo cual deberia de mostrarme true, llevo varios dias tratando de dar solución a esto y nada . A continuación dejo mi código esperando que me puedan ayudar. MUCHAS GRACIAS.
[image: Codigo PHP][image: Codigo HTML]

La base de datos es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, añade el código directamente a la pregunta en lugar de poner imágenes del código

Comment: El puerto de mysql normalmente es 3306, lo has cambiado?

Comment: fijate que aparece en el error.log de apache! .

Comment: ¿Podrías incluir también la estructura de la tabla `t_usuarios`?

Comment: El puerto MySql no lo cambie, solo el de Apache y la tabla t_usuarios la dejo a continuación

Answer (score 1):

Yo tengo otras anotaciones que agregar a lo que comentan mis compañeros de stack.

> 1. Revisar que la conexión a BD se este realizando correctamente, como te comentaron el puerto por default es 3306.
> 2. Una ves que tengas éxito con la conexión pasas a la ejecución de tu consulta SQL para ver si de en verdad la estas haciendo de una
>      manera correcta.
> 3. Por último pasas a probar tu código php.

Answer (score 1):

Hola viendo tu codigo desde la linea 26 a la linea 30, donde realizas la consulta no veo en ningun lado donde defines a  ':usuario' ademas veo que esta incorrecta tu consulta ya que deberia ser :

```
$usuario=$_SESSION['usuario'];
SELECT * FROM t_usuarios WHERE usuario='$usuario' LIMIT 1;
```

Por otro lado veo que el puerto para la conexion a Mysql es diferente y deberia ser el Puerto:3306, como te indica Jose

Answer (score 0):

¿Has verificado con un echo el valor que está recibiendo la variable $usuario?;  otro punto,¿que te está devolviendo el var_dump podrías copiar el resultado?

Puedes confirmar si en realidad el servidor MYSQL está corriendo en puerto 8080, ya que este usualmente es usado por un servidor TOMCAT

Con esa información creo que podría ayudarte,

Saludos

Comment: Cuando imprimo el resultado me sale el mismo que tengo en la Base de Datos